# Scala generic type matching

Tags: scala, generics, casting

Frequently, I find myself doing pattern matching such as this

```
val foo: Foo = ...
foo match {
  case bar: Bar => Some(bar)
  case _ => None
}
```

I want to make this shorter.

```
val foo: Foo = ...
optInstance[Foo, Bar](foo)
```

**Possibility 1 - direct translation**

```
def optInstance[A, B <: A](a: A) = a match {
  case b: B => Some(b)
  case _ => None
}
// warning: abstract type pattern B is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
```

**Possibility 2 - try-catch**

```
def optInstance[A, B <: A](a: A) =
  try {
    Some(a.asInstanceOf[B])
  } catch {
    case e: ClassCastException => None
  }
// no warnings
```

**Possiblility 3 - if-else**

```
def optInstance[A, B <: A](a: A) =
  if(a.isInstanceOf[B]) {
    Some(a.asInstanceOf[B])
  } else {
    None
  }
// no warnings
```

None of them work. (Scala 2.11.2)

---

Is there a generic way of writing

```
foo match {
  case bar: Bar => Some(bar)
  case _ => None
}
```

(If not, is there at least a shorter way?)

Comment: What is foo when it's not a Bar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cleaner way using implicit value class:

```
 implicit class AsOpt[A](val a: A) extends AnyVal {
   def asOpt[B <: A : scala.reflect.ClassTag]: Option[B] = a match {
     case b: B => Some(b)
     case _    => None
   }
 }
```

Example:

```
 val seq: Seq[Int] = Seq.empty
 seq.asOpt[List[Int]]   // Option[List[Int]] = Some(List())
 seq.asOpt[Vector[Int]] // Option[Vector[Int]] = None
```

Comment: Love it. I had intended to do that, after I figured out `ClassTag`. And  good use of value classes.

Answer (score 4):

Just add an implicit `ClassTag` for your first implementation:

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

def optInstance[A, B <: A : ClassTag](a: A): Option[B] = a match {
  case b: B => Some(b)
  case _ => None
}
```

Example:

```
sealed trait Foo
case object Bar extends Foo
case object Baz extends Foo

scala> optInstance[Foo, Bar.type](Bar)
res4: Option[Bar.type] = Some(Bar)

scala> optInstance[Foo, Bar.type](Baz)
res5: Option[Bar.type] = None
```

Comment: Does that still work with types that aren't just "classes"...like traits?

Answer (score 1):

Without a generic function you can use `Option` and `collect`:

```
class Foo
class Bar extends Foo
class Baz extends Foo

scala> val foo: Foo = new Bar
scala> Some(foo).collect { case b: Bar => b }
res1: Option[Bar] = Some(Bar@483edb6b)

scala> val baz: Foo = new Baz
scala> Some(baz).collect { case b: Bar => b }
res3: Option[Bar] = None
```